# Type mismatch in key from map: expected .. Text, received ... LongWritable

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a simple hadoop application, which get one CSV file, then split the entry by ",", then count the first items.

The following is my code.

```
package com.bluedolphin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MyJob extends Configured implements Tool {
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);


    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
        private Text word = new Text();
        public void map(Object key, 
                    Text value, 
                    OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output,
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] citation = value.toString().split(",");
            word.set(citation[0]);
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void reduce(
                Text key, 
                Iterator<LongWritable> values, 
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output,
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new LongWritable(sum));
        }
    }
    public static class Combiner extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void reduce(
                Text key, 
                Iterator<LongWritable> values, 
                OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output,
                Reporter reporter) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;

            while (values.hasNext()) {
                sum += values.next().get();
            }
            output.collect(key, new LongWritable(sum));

        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();

        Job job = new Job(conf, "MyJob");
        job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class);

        Path in = new Path(args[0]);
        Path out = new Path(args[1]);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    //  job.setCombinerClass(Combiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    //  job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueInputFormat.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    //  job.setOutputFormatClass(KeyValueOutputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyJob(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
11/12/16 22:16:58 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112161948_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:690)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couple of things to be fixed in the code

1. The old (o.a.h.mapred) and the new API (o.a.h.mapreduce) are not compatible, so they should not be mixed.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;  
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;  
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;  
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;  
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
```

2. Make sure the input/output for the mappers/reducers are of the type o.a.h.io.Writable. The input key for the Mapper is Object, make it LongWritable.
3. Looks like the Combiner and the Reducer functionality is the same, so you need not repeat it.

```
job.setCombinerClass(Reducer.class);
```

Also, you could use the [WordCount](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/mapred_tutorial.html) example, there is not much difference between your requirement and the WordCount example.

Comment: The &lt; and &gt; was striped by the page, so I escaped them and added it back, please have a look again. Thank.

Comment: Pretty old post, but I must say the usage of the Combiner is not redundant: it is used to improve the performance of the job, please see http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce

Answer (score 6):

A general note, if we have a `Mapper<K1,V1, K2,V2>` and `Reducer<K2,V2, K3,V3>` it is better to declare (in the Job) the following

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(MyJob.class);
...
conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(K2.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(V2.class);
```

You can see another example [here](http://brianoneill.blogspot.com/2009/07/hadoop-javaioioexception-type-mismatch.html).

Answer (score 0):

Old API (o.a.h.mapred) and new API (o.a.h.mapreduce) are not compatible, so they should not be mixed.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
```

You should try replacing the OutputCollector and Reporter in Map and Reduce functions signature with Context.
map(K1 key,V1 val,Context context) and output.collect(k,v) with context.write(k,v)

For reference use this link with more details on migrating to new API
http://www.slideshare.net/sh1mmer/upgrading-to-the-new-map-reduce-api#