# IOException after mapping before reducing

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have a dataset, each record in which consists of 2 fields:

- URL (without prefix);
- life time (in seconds).

I want to compute avrage lifetime **in days** for each domain. I. e. if I have such  2 records:

```
hadoop.apache.org/docs/current 22118400
hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/ 27820800
```

I should receive answer:

```
hadoop.apache.org 289
```

For these computings I wrote a hadoop-job:

```
package ru.bdata.siteslifes;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import ru.bdata.siteslifes.arrays.IntArrayWritable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

    public static class DomainMapper extends Mapper<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(Text key, IntWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            String url = key.toString();
            context.write(new Text(url.substring(0, url.indexOf('/'))), value);
        }
    }

    public static class AvgCombiner extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>{
        private static final int SEC_IN_DAY = 86400;

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context)
                throws IOException,InterruptedException{
            float sum = 0;
            int cnt = 0;
            Iterator<IntWritable> it = value.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                sum += it.next().get();
                cnt++;
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(Math.round(sum / (cnt * SEC_IN_DAY))));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] strings) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(AvgSiteLifeCounter.class);

        job.setMapperClass(DomainMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(AvgCombiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(8);

        SequenceFileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(strings[0]));
        SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(strings[1]));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0: 1;
    }
}
```

When I execute program on a cluster, mapping-part works well, but before the reducer-part starts, I see an Exception:

```
java.io.IOException: wrong key class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text is not class org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.append(SequenceFile.java:1305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat$1.write(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.write(WrappedReducer.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.reduce(Reducer.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:610)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.ja...
```

How I should change my code to make the reduce-part working too?

As this Job is only part of hadoop-task, input and output data represented as binary files (`SequenceFile`).

P.S. As you can see, I don't use `LongWritable`. Only `IntWritable`. But in the log of Exception I see `LongWritable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542324/type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-expected-text-received-longwritable?rq=1. If not, can you paste your import statements too?

Comment: Imports was added. No, it's not duplicate. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542324/type-mismatch-in-key-from-map-expected-text-received-longwritable?rq=1 there was used old API (for example, org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector) and new API simultaneously. This is bad style because these APIs are incompatible.

Comment: But adding conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); solved my problem. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After **map-stage** Hadoop writes results to the temporary file and after them **reducer** reads this data. In `run()` method there were no key and value settings of data, which must be read from temporary file.
So, my code has become works after setting key and value for the results of mapper. I.e. I added in run() method such strings:

```
conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its bit confusing that Hadoop gives IO exception when there is really a type mismatch between the one job knows set by driver code and types actually  received at runtime.